# Visual Studio Professional 2022 installer crashes

Tags: windows, visual-studio, antivirus, mcafee

I've been trying to upgrade to VS Pro 2022 from VS Pro 2019 and have eventually ended up in the position where I have managed to uninstall the older versions whilst the new version crashes on installation.

The dd_installer_XXX.log file concludes with the following exception:

```
[3cb0:0004][2021-12-03T17:23:35] Telemetry property vs.willow.processtype : ui
[3cb0:0001][2021-12-03T17:23:36] Adding Install Log to Watson=C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_installer_20211203172335.log
[3cb0:0001][2021-12-03T17:23:38] Error 0x57f50000: Unhandled exception has occurred: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Unknown error (0x57f50000)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetParent(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.GetParent(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.UpdateWindowPos(IntPtr lParam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

So far I've tried applying all the available Windows updates and am now on Win 10 version 20H2 OS Build 19042.1387. I've also tried uninstalling all Visual Studio components and deleting the Microsoft Visual Studio folder from the program files directory and prior to that running InstallCleanup.exe. The device is a Lenovo ThinkPad T480.

Has anyone else had problems like this and been able to resolve them? My next port of call is to ask the service desk if it's possible to get McAfee disabled during the installation process as that's a piece of software I don't particularly trust...

Comment: The service desk should be your first port of call.

Answer (score 0):

Worked with our service desk to disable the McAfee AV but the installer still crashed.  It seems likely that it is related to this:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visual-studio-2022-installation-fails-because-of-m/1578946

Eventually we were able to work around this problem by using Chocolatey to install the program from here: https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/visualstudio2022professional